# error in using fftoneside

Tags: matlab, window, fft

Hi I'm trying to calculate mfcc for which i'm windowing. I have seen this one post I'm getting error in fftOneSide.
my code is

```
    waveFile='test_preEmphasis.wav';
    [y, fs]=wavread(waveFile);

    n=512;
    t=(1:n)'/fs;
    startIndex=30418;
    endIndex=startIndex+n-1;

    original=y(startIndex:endIndex);
    windowed=original.*hamming(n);
    [mag1, phase1, freq1]=fftOneSide(original, fs);
    [mag2, phase2, freq2]=fftOneSide(windowed, fs);

    subplot(3,2,1); plot(original); grid on; axis([-inf inf -1 1]); 
    title('Original signal');
    subplot(3,2,2); plot(windowed); grid on; axis([-inf inf -1 1]);  
    title('Windowedsignal');
    subplot(3,2,3); plot(freq1, mag1); grid on; 
    title('Energy spectrum (linear scale)');
    subplot(3,2,4); plot(freq2, mag2); grid on; 
    title('Energy spectrum (linear scale)');
    subplot(3,2,5); plot(freq1, 20*log(mag1)); grid on; 
    axis([-inf inf -80 120]); title('Energy spectrum (db)');
    subplot(3,2,6); plot(freq2, 20*log(mag2)); grid on; axis([-inf inf -80 120]);  
    title('Energy spectrum (db)');
```

the error i'm getting is

```
    ??? Undefined function or method 'fftOneSide' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

any help is appreciated
thanks

Comment: What's the definition of `fftOneSide`? It's not a standard Matlab function

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm posting link of webpage I was using [http://neural.cs.nthu.edu.tw/jang/books/audiosignalprocessing/speechfeaturemfcc.asp?title=12-2%20mfcc]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really old post, it'd be neat if someone still cared. I just provided what I believe to be the answer in the recent post below, which I arrived at after a fair bit of frustration: [Undefined function 'fftOneSide' for input arguments of type 'double'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337701/undefined-function-fftoneside-for-input-arguments-of-type-double/35338126#35338126).

It should be noted here there's a call to a file, which I'm not sure if the author had originally or not. I suspect all the problems are related to a similarly named file in the sourcecode.

If you look at my discussion in the other post, within the function definition there is a call to a method `demo` with a file - which isn't present if you just have the function definition, not the original file. Calling `[mag1, phase1, freq1]=fftOneSide(original, fs,1)`, after you comment out the first line `if nargin <1...` and the `demo` routine worked fine on my machine with the code which I'll show below. Having the third argument equal to 1 guarantees that the code will run the print routines, which is important.

In case the other thread is closed, I just want to show the output, when the input is manually defined, and I call `[mag1, phase1, freq1]=fftOneSide(original, fs,1)` on the properly edited method, with the inputs as in the original post shown below (notice the call is to `original` in `fftOneSide`..in the other post it was like this as well.. I believe the call was was meant to be instead for `windowed`, but I don't have the signals toolbox with `hamming` anyways):

```
fs=8000;
t=(1:512)'/fs; %'// <-- prevents string markdown
f=306.396;
original=sin(2*pi*f*t)+0.2*randn(length(t),1);
% windowed=original.*hamming(length(t)); % defined in other post
[mag1,phase1,freq1]=fftOneSide(original,fs); % I call fftOneSide(original,fs,1);
```

The output is as follows (source code below!)

[image: output from fftOneSide]

Anyways, here's the source code in case anyone wants to use this function

```
function [magSpec, phaseSpec, freq, powerSpecInDb]=fftOneSide(signal, fs, plotOpt) 
% fftOneSide: One-sided FFT for real signals 
%   Usage: [magSpec, phaseSpec, freq, powerSpecInDb]=fftOneSide(signal, fs) 
% 
%   For example: 
%       [y, fs]=wavread('welcome.wav'); 
%       frameSize=512; 
%       startIndex=2047; 
%       signal=y(startIndex:startIndex+frameSize+1); 
%       signal=signal.*hamming(length(signal)); 
%       plotOpt=1; 
%       [magSpec, phaseSpec, freq, powerSpecInDb]=fftOneSide(signal, fs, plotOpt); 

%   Roger Jang, 20060411, 20070506 

if nargin<1, selfdemo; return; end %=== (MathBio: Comment this out!)
if nargin<2, fs=1; end 
if nargin<3, plotOpt=0; end 

N = length(signal);         % Signal length 
freqStep = fs/N;            % Frequency resolution 
time = (0:N-1)/fs;          % Time vector 
z = fft(signal);            % Spectrum 
freq = freqStep*(0:N/2);        % Frequency vector 
z = z(1:length(freq));          % One side 
z(2:end-1)=2*z(2:end-1);        % Assuming N is even, symmetric data is multiplied by 2
magSpec=abs(z);             % Magnitude spectrum 
phaseSpec=unwrap(angle(z));     % Phase spectrum 
powerSpecInDb=20*log(magSpec+realmin);  % Power in db 

if plotOpt 
    % ====== Plot time-domain signals 
    subplot(3,1,1); 
    plot(time, signal, '.-'); 
    title(sprintf('Input signals (fs=%d)', fs)); 
    xlabel('Time (seconds)'); ylabel('Amplitude'); axis tight 
    % ====== Plot spectral power 
    subplot(3,1,2); 
    plot(freq, powerSpecInDb, '.-'); grid on 
    title('Power spectrum'); 
    xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('Power (db)'); axis tight 
    % ====== Plot phase 
    subplot(3,1,3); 
    plot(freq, phaseSpec, '.-'); grid on 
    title('Phase'); 
    xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('Phase (Radian)'); axis tight 
    end 

% ====== Self demo (MathBio: Comment all of this out! )
function selfdemo 
[y, fs]=wavread('welcome.wav'); 
frameSize=512; 
startIndex=2047; 
signal=y(startIndex:startIndex+frameSize+1); 
signal=signal.*hamming(length(signal)); 
[magSpec, phaseSpec, freq, powerSpecInDb]=feval(mfilename, signal, fs, 1);
```