# Undefined function 'fftOneSide' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB R2013.

```
fs=8000;
t=(1:512)'/fs; %'// <-- prevents string markdown
f=306.396;
original=sin(2*pi*f*t)+0.2*randn(length(t),1);
windowed=original.*hamming(length(t));
[mag1,phase1,freq1]=fftOneSide(original,fs);
```

Error:

> Undefined function 'fftOneSide' for input arguments of type 'double'

Comment: @trix I rolled back your edit because it did change the code

Answer (score 1):

This question was raised in a previous SO question, with apparently no response until now:
[error in using fftoneside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535738/error-in-using-fftoneside)

Using your input for the signal, without using the hamming function (I don't have the signal toolbox on my computer), after defining the function below (I commented out the demo code at the bottom part and the first line with `if nargin <1` obv!!), I ran it on Matlab2015a. It ran fine! Setting `plotOpt=1` (that is calling with three arguments, the final equal to 1) provides proof:

[image: output from fftOneSide]

The only thing I can think of, is that in the sourcecode it asks for a file as input - which I'm assuming you don't have. If you comment out the `nargin <1` part, and the whole selfdemo at the end, see if this doesn't work as you want it to. If it doesn't, I'm completely baffled!

I've taken a look at the source code (below) for this function, which also shows proper usage. As you can see they're reading the signal and `fs` values in from a file, rather than defining them as you have here. It's a bit of a pain we can't see what values they chose.

Notice the call asks for `plotOpt` to be specified, though if you don't specify it, the `nargin` calls at the beginning should set it to 0 for you (right?). I don't think default function declarations have changed since 2012 - but if they have, calling the function with three arguments will take care of that. Note: if don't set plotOpt=1, the plots won't proceed.

http://read.pudn.com/downloads99/sourcecode/others/404673/audioProcessing/fftOneSide.m__.htm

```
function [magSpec, phaseSpec, freq, powerSpecInDb]=fftOneSide(signal, fs, plotOpt) 
% fftOneSide: One-sided FFT for real signals 
%   Usage: [magSpec, phaseSpec, freq, powerSpecInDb]=fftOneSide(signal, fs) 
% 
%   For example: 
%       [y, fs]=wavread('welcome.wav'); 
%       frameSize=512; 
%       startIndex=2047; 
%       signal=y(startIndex:startIndex+frameSize+1); 
%       signal=signal.*hamming(length(signal)); 
%       plotOpt=1; 
%       [magSpec, phaseSpec, freq, powerSpecInDb]=fftOneSide(signal, fs, plotOpt); 

%   Roger Jang, 20060411, 20070506 

if nargin<1, selfdemo; return; end % MBio: comment out
if nargin<2, fs=1; end 
if nargin<3, plotOpt=0; end 

N = length(signal);         % Signal length 
freqStep = fs/N;            % Frequency resolution 
time = (0:N-1)/fs;          % Time vector 
z = fft(signal);            % Spectrum 
freq = freqStep*(0:N/2);        % Frequency vector 
z = z(1:length(freq));          % One side 
z(2:end-1)=2*z(2:end-1);        % Assuming N is even, symmetric data is multiplied by 2
magSpec=abs(z);             % Magnitude spectrum 
phaseSpec=unwrap(angle(z));     % Phase spectrum 
powerSpecInDb=20*log(magSpec+realmin);  % Power in db 

if plotOpt 
    % ====== Plot time-domain signals 
    subplot(3,1,1); 
    plot(time, signal, '.-'); 
    title(sprintf('Input signals (fs=%d)', fs)); 
    xlabel('Time (seconds)'); ylabel('Amplitude'); axis tight 
    % ====== Plot spectral power 
    subplot(3,1,2); 
    plot(freq, powerSpecInDb, '.-'); grid on 
    title('Power spectrum'); 
    xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('Power (db)'); axis tight 
    % ====== Plot phase 
    subplot(3,1,3); 
    plot(freq, phaseSpec, '.-'); grid on 
    title('Phase'); 
    xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('Phase (Radian)'); axis tight 
end 

% ====== Self demo MBio: comment ALL this code out! 
function selfdemo 
[y, fs]=wavread('welcome.wav'); 
frameSize=512; 
startIndex=2047; 
signal=y(startIndex:startIndex+frameSize+1); 
signal=signal.*hamming(length(signal)); 
[magSpec, phaseSpec, freq, powerSpecInDb]=feval(mfilename, signal, fs, 1);
```